# R error in eval Function

Tags: r, function, eval

hi all I'm trying to create a function in R to clean data... the following code is part of it.

```
limpio=function (tabla, campo, campo_conteo){

  tabla1<-aggregate(campo_conteo ~ campo, tabla, length)
  colnames(tabla1)[2]<-"frecuencia"
  tabla2 <- gsub('\\s+','',toupper(tabla1$campo)) 
  View(tabla2) }
```

So, when I run:

```
limpio(vendidos, Nacionality, CustomerID)
```

I get the following error:

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'CustomerID' not found

But the column does exist, so don't know what's the problem.

```
colnames(vendidos)

 #[1] "ID"             "CampaignID"     "CustomerID"     "PhoneID"        "Name"          
 #[6] "NumberType"     "Number"         "Birthday"       "Sex"            "Holder"        
#[11] "HolderNumber"   "Nacionality"    "Address"        "City"           "Zip"
```

Comment: I would try limpo(vendidos, Nacionality, vendidos[,2]). From the information you gave, there don't seem to have any Nacionality in your table vendidos though.

Comment: I have it, I only showed part of the columns.

Comment: Do you have any errors with the method suggested above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't create a formula object like this. You need to pass characters to the function and create the formula from those:

```
limpio <- function (tabla, campo, campo_conteo){
  f <- as.formula(paste(campo_conteo, campo, sep="~"))
  tabla1<-aggregate(f, tabla, length)
  colnames(tabla1)[2]<-"frecuencia"
  gsub('\\s+','',toupper(tabla1$campo)) 
  }

limpio(vendidos, "Nacionality", "CustomerID")
```

Alternatively, you could use the non-formula `aggregate` method.

Comment: With your code I get the following error: Error: unexpected '}' in "                  gsub('\\s+','',toupper(tabla1$campo)) }"

Comment: I've added the missing parenthesis. That's what happens if you don't provide a reproducible example for testing. You get to fix typos yourself.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see it.